# iphone iCloud app crashes when compiling on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, compiler-errors, icloud

I'd like to use an iCloud, but when I compile the app on iOS 4.3 Simulator it crashes.

dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMetadataQuery

What should I do to make it working on iOS 3, 4, and 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These API has been launched with the ios5 so you cann't run it on the simulator 4 or below but for posting you can set the minimum deployment target of ios family it should support .

Comment: I have iOS Deployment Target set to 3.0.

Comment: then it will give problem until you don't post it on the app store it is app store deployment target not to development testing target ..

Comment: so I can't test the app on the device with iOS 4?

Comment: no you only can develop the app on ios 5 and put the deployment target for lower os it's apple's responsibility to support this facility on those devices after launching on the app store.

Comment: ok, thanks, I hope when I send an app to AppStore, users with IOS 3 and 4 will be able to install it :)

Comment: no just set you deployment sdk and base sdk (generally it is the updated one ) the app will specify on which it can install and supported os on its itunes links.

Comment: Although you say NSClassFromString does not work for you, still be sure to check what is available on the users phone. If you don't do it, you'll have problems with user below iOS 5.0.

Comment: I don't agree with Ballu here. You can install the iOS 4 simulator, and then run your app there. If it does not run its your problem, not Apples. When you set the minimum IOS deployment target to anything other than 'latest iOS' you need to be an experienced developer to get it to run on older versions of iOS.

Comment: Most apps will not be able to run with the sdk set to iOS 5 on an iOS 3 device. There are just too many differences.

Comment: Ok Tom add a icloud api from ios 5 to your xcode 4.2 and then run it on the os below then 4.2 you will get the result may be you can get the complie time error it's all depend what the framework you are using and was that available in last os.But if you make the app on updated sdk and set the deployment target then apple documentation says that it will be install on the os specified in the plist of the app during submission to app store. pls check this http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/base-sdk-and-iphone-os-deployment-target-developing-apps-with-the-4-x-sdk-deploying-to-3-x-devices.html

Comment: It's definitely possible to access this API conditionally while still operating without it on older runtimes.  See the answer by NguyenHungA5 for details.  You need to dynamically load the class, but it works just fine.  It's also possible to target iOS 6 (and later...) as the target SDK with a minimum deployment target as low as 3.1.3.  Only tricky part is you need to use an older Xcode (4.4.1) to build a binary that's compatible with the older devices.

Answer (score 6):

my sulotion is:

Where have NSMetadataQuery change to id: ex

normal : - (void)loadData:(NSMetadataQuery *)query;
change to: - (void)loadData:(id)query;

normal: @property (retain, nonatomic) NSMetadataQuery *query;
change to: @property (retain, nonatomic) id query;

and check iCloud available:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] respondsToSelector:@selector(URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:)]) {
        NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
        if (ubiq) {
            // Code for access iCloud here
        }
    }
```

When use NSMetadataQuery:

```
id _query = [[NSClassFromString(@"NSMetadataQuery") alloc] init];
// Some code here
[_query startQuery];
```

Have fun (^_^)

Comment: The important part here is the `[[NSClassFromString(@"NSMetadataQuery") alloc] init]`. You *can not* use `[NSMetadataQuery alloc]`.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way would be to compile it with iOS 5 SDK and setting the deployment target to the oldest iOS Version you'd like it to work with. It's up to you though to check at runtime on which classes and methods are available to the current system. A user on iOS 4 for example will not be able to use functions that only ship with iOS 5.

To check the availability of classes do:

```
if ( NSClassFromString(@"NSMetadataQuery") != nil ) {
  //do stuff with NSMetadataQuery here
}
```

To check the availability of methods do:

```
if ( [myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething)] ) {
  //call doSomething on myObject
}
```

Comment: I used NSClassFromString but that not help. I get the same error.

Comment: I would not bother with anything other than iOS 4.3 and iOS 5. There are so many things that are not there in 3. Also people who buy stuff on the app store likely have updated phones.

Comment: This post is helpful to show how users versions break down for Instapaper, a popular app http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper. Short version- don't do iOS5-only unless you need to, but iOS4-only and up is fine.