# Can an iOS app built against the 5.0 SDK run on iOS 4.3?

Tags: ios, xcode

My app doesn't have any iOS 5.0 specific code but I just downloaded Xcode 4.2 and need to make an update to my app but see I just have the 5.0 SDK.  If I build against this SDK, will it force all users to have 5.0 before using the app?

Comment: If you decide to add iOS specific stuff, check out this question on how to handle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834645/iphone-icloud-app-crashes-when-compiling-on-ios-4/7835045#7835045

Answer (score 5):

No it will not force users to use iOS 5. Just set the Build Settings -> Deployment -> iOS Deployment Target to the appropriate value.

Comment: hi, where can I find this setting... here's screenshot of Build Settings in my test project on xcode 4.2 http://i.imgur.com/P4Buj.png

Comment: search for deployment, you'll see it